# How to remove empty values from array?

Tags: php

```
Array (
      [0] => Angiogram - $10,000    
      [1] => 
      [2] => 
      [3] => 
      )
```

This is my array format and I need to remove all empty index from this array. I tried Using `array_filter()` but it is not working. Please help.
I need result like:

```
Array([0]=> Angiogram-$10,000)
```

Comment: `$array = array_filter($array);` works perfectly well

Comment: array_filter is not working , Thanks For the reply

Comment: Then you don't have empty elements! What is the output of: `var_dump($arr);` ?

Comment: [DEMO](http://3v4l.org/B3LOE) of array_filter() working for your array (as posted here)

Comment: But i get the same the same initial array format by using array_filter Array (
      [0] => Angiogram - $10,000    
      [1] => 
      [2] => 
      [3] => 
      )

Comment: Do a var_dump() of your array to see what it really contains

Comment: Show your actual `php` code where you have tried

Comment: This is my var dump resultarray(4) {
  [0]=> string(114) "Angiogram - $10,000"
  [1]=>string(65) ""                                
  [2]=>string(51) ""    
  [3]=>string(37) ""                     
}

Comment: `string(65) ""` suggests a lot of hidden characters such as nulls in a 65-byte string, clearly it isn't empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
 $array=array("Angiogram - $10,000","","","","");
 $removeempty=array_filter($array);
 print_r($removeempty);

  or

$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', $array));
print_r($array);

    Ans:

    Array ( [0] => Angiogram - $10,000 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try like this,

```
array_filter(array_map('trim', $array))
```

Comment: Simplify even further to `$myArray = array_filter($myArray, 'trim');` and eliminate the need to call `array_map()` completely

Answer (score 0):

If array_filter($array) doesn't work it means that you array isn't empty!

Try this:

```
$array = array("1", "2", "3", "","5");


$clearArray = var_dump(removeEmpty($array));

function removeEmpty($array) {
  return array_filter($array, 'removeEmpty_internal');
}

function removeEmpty_internal($value) {
  return !empty($value) || $value === 0;
}
```